# How to prefill field in lightning:recordForm OR use standard layout in lightning:recordEditForm

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to prefill a field when creating a record in LWC. I need to use the standard layout and all I need is to fill the value of one field on it.

I see that for some reason, this is not supported on the regular recordForm component, everyone suggests using the recordEditForm but as far as I can tell, this doesn't have an option for using the standard layout at all.

Is there any way around these restrictions, or at least a reason that these restrictions exist in the first place? I don't want to have to create a custom copy of our standard layout and maintain it forever just to prefill a single field.

Answer (score 0):

1. We cannot set default values using `onload` event as the record we get will be `immutable` .
2. We can get `fields` in event `onsubmit` but that will be a copy of original fields and changing the field in this copy will not affect the original fields due to which you cannot use standard `submit()` behaviour .

You can load the standard layout and while submitting, collect the `fields`, process them according to your need and upsert the record in apex yourself.

HTML:

```
<lightning-record-form object-api-name="Account"
                           layout-type="Compact"
                           columns="2"
                           onload={handleLoad}
                           onsubmit={handleSubmit}
                           mode="edit">
    </lightning-record-form>
```

JS:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.detail.fields.Rating = 'Hot';
    saveAccount({ account: {sobjectType:'Account',...event.detail.fields} })
    .then(res => console.log('SUCCESS'))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

However using this, user will not know that you are setting a field by default unless you show some info in page about it. The above way may not be suitable in majority of cases for this reason. The only other option is to use `record-edit-form`